# Wordpress on Azure Regular Brief Downtimes

Tags: wordpress, azure, cloudflare

I have a Wordpress site running on Windows Azure (under Azure websites). Recently I keep getting brief downtimes. I'm getting `Error establishing database connection` quick frequently, and sporadically the pages won't load (no error messages, just site down). With any of these, the site will be available again within a few minutes max, without me doing anything. The database settings are correct, I haven't been notified of any Azure issues, and I'm using CloudFlare but I don't think the issue is with them (?). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A database connection error wouldn't be a CloudFlare issue, really. Are you seeing any [CloudFlare error messages](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038216-CloudFlare-Error-Messages)?

Comment: No, no CloudFlare errors - either the site won't load at all, or there's a db error

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by the idle-timeout of the website.

If you don't get a request to your site within 20 minutes, the site will go into sleep.

When the next request comes an startup will have to take place, and since this sometimes is a slow process (specificaly if it's a Azure website free), this might lead to a connection timeout.

The sequent calls to the site will succeed.

Comment: I see - do you know what I can do to prevent that happening?

Comment: I would recommend using this guide to setup a ping to your page to simulate traffic every 20 minutes. http://ideasof.andersaberg.com/idea/14/keep-your-free-azure-website-from-idle-app-pool-timeout

Comment: I already tried setting up Pingdom and Statuscake, which ping the site more regularly than every 20 minutes, but that didn't solve it. Also, I'm on the Bizspark package, should I still need to be doing this?